# Magento 2: Disable add to cart button for certain products in category page

Tags: magento2, module, addtocart

I am doing a custom module and now I want to hide the 'add to cart' button for certain products.
I have followed the `https://magenticians.com/magento-2-disable-add-to-cart-button/` documentation and i was able to hide it from the product's detail page but not from the home/category page. I need this button hidden from all the views.

I have added the `addtocart.phtml` file to `app/code/Magenticians/Mymodule/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view` path and also the corresponding layout file as the document link said. 
It is working in detail page of the product only. I want it on all pages.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to Cart button is not a separate file for the product listing page. You need to add your Add to Cart phtml file customization to the `list.phtml` file.

Copy `list.phtml` file from below path to your theme and make the required changes you've done in the `addtocart.phtml` file.

```
\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list.phtml
```

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

For overriding list.phtml

Create view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml and put this code.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magenticians_Mymodule::product/list.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

after, copy 
`\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list.phtml`
and paste it to
`view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml` then make yur modifications